# Assign one row of 2d array to 1d array

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to assign one row of 2d array to 1d array this is what i want to do.
`int words[40][16];
int arrtemp[16];
                arrtemp=words[i];`

Comment: Using `std::array` or `std::vector` will give you the syntax you're looking for, and better in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are immutable in C and C++. You can't reassign them.

You can use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(arrtemp, words[i], 16 * sizeof(int) );
```

This copies `16 * sizeof(int)` bytes from `words[i]` to `arrtemp`.

Comment: That's a strange use of the word immutable.  I've only ever heard the word immutable used to describe objects whose contents can't change.

Answer (score 5):

Use [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
int words[40][16]; //Be sure to initialise words and i at some point
int arrtemp[16];
//If you don't have std::begin and std::end,
//use boost::begin and boost::end (from Boost.Range) or
//std::copy(words[i] + 0, words[i] + 16, arrtemp + 0) instead.
std::copy(std::begin(words[i]), std::end(words[i]), std::begin(arrtemp));
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, I thought it did.

Comment: `std::begin()` and `std::end()` where added in C++11, but you could use `std::copy(words[0], words[0] + 16, arrtemp);` in pre C++11.

Comment: @hmjd: Or use `boost::begin` and `boost::end` (or just `boost::copy` which is better than `std::copy` anyway).